# How to order columns by numbers in R?

Tags: r, columnsorting

I have data.frame with the column names shown in the example.
V1.1 = test series 1, day 1, K1-K3 are three unique samples. I want to order my columns by days, so that the order would be V1.1, V1.2, V1.14, V1.21. I think that this is no big problem, but I can't find the correct answer for my problem in the forum.

```
  A tibble: 6 x 168
      genus V1.1.K1 V1.1.K2 V1.1.K3 V1.14.K16 V1.14.K17 V1.14.K18 V1.2.K4 V1.2.K5 V1.2.K6 V1.21.K19 V1.21.K20 V1.21.K21
      <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
    1 A17        58       7      78         0         0         0       0       0       0         0         0         0
    2 Acan~       0       0       0         0         0         0       0       0       0         0         0         0
    3 Acet~       8       0       5       155       256       341       0      28      26       188       142        83
    4 Achr~       0       0       0         0         0         0       0       0       0         0         0         0
    5 Acid~       0       0       7         0         0         0       0      83       6        43        13         0
    6 Acid~       0       0       0         0         0         0       0       0       0         0         0         0
```

First, I tried to solve the problem with

```
select(1:3, 7:9, 4:5, 11:13)
```

But then it is not reproducible to other data.frames, I am working with, because there the amount of colums or the days are different.

Or is there an argument to add to my data-import, which is done by

```
read_tsv()
```

?
You would help me a lot :)
Kathrin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want them ordered by the numbers, disregarding the letters (or lexicographic sorts), then here's a way. Since you're using `select`, I'll infer you have `%>%` and others.

```r
library(magrittr) # %>%, not needed if you have dplyr loaded
library(stringr)  # str_extract_all
ord <- str_extract_all(names(dat), "\\d+") %>%
  lapply(., `length<-`, max(lengths(.))) %>%
  lapply(., as.integer) %>%
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, .) %>%
  do.call(function(...) order(..., na.last = FALSE), .)

ord
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  8  9 10  5  6  7 11 12 13
dat[,ord]      # or select(dat, all_of(ord))
#   genus V1.1.K1 V1.1.K2 V1.1.K3 V1.2.K4 V1.2.K5 V1.2.K6 V1.14.K16 V1.14.K17 V1.14.K18 V1.21.K19 V1.21.K20 V1.21.K21
# 1   A17      58       7      78       0       0       0         0         0         0         0         0         0
# 2 Acan~       0       0       0       0       0       0         0         0         0         0         0         0
# 3 Acet~       8       0       5       0      28      26       155       256       341       188       142        83
# 4 Achr~       0       0       0       0       0       0         0         0         0         0         0         0
# 5 Acid~       0       0       7       0      83       6         0         0         0        43        13         0
# 6 Acid~       0       0       0       0       0       0         0         0         0         0         0         0
```

The `na.last=FALSE` forces (in this case) `genus` to be first. If you have various names with and without numbers, you may get inconsistent results, in which case you may need to subset the column names you use with this.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(genus = c("A17", "Acan~", "Acet~", "Achr~", "Acid~", "Acid~"), V1.1.K1 = c(58L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V1.1.K2 = c(7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V1.1.K3 = c(78L, 0L, 5L, 0L, 7L, 0L), V1.14.K16 = c(0L, 0L, 155L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V1.14.K17 = c(0L, 0L, 256L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V1.14.K18 = c(0L, 0L, 341L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V1.2.K4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), V1.2.K5 = c(0L, 0L, 28L, 0L, 83L, 0L), V1.2.K6 = c(0L, 0L, 26L, 0L, 6L, 0L), V1.21.K19 = c(0L, 0L, 188L, 0L, 43L, 0L), V1.21.K20 = c(0L, 0L, 142L, 0L, 13L, 0L), V1.21.K21 = c(0L, 0L, 83L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: That solved the problem, thank you :) In the case I want to order for example due to the K1 - K21 values, would it be okay to change the command like this: `ord <- str_extract_all(names(dat), "(K[1-9]{1,2})") %>%
  lapply(., `length<-`, max(lengths(.))) %>%
  lapply(., as.integer) %>%
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, .) %>%
  do.call(function(...) order(..., na.last = FALSE), .)`
?

Comment: FYI, the first `lapply` (using `\`length<-\``) is merely defensive, ensuring that all of the columns' names contain the same number of numbers; this condition is necessary for the `rbind.data.frame`. Even if you know that all columns with numbers have 3 numbers, the presence of `"genus"` here breaks that trend, as it has 0. Just an FYI.

Comment: Well, you tell me ... you wanted to sort by all of the numbers in each name, but your regex returns just `"K1"` and such. First, you won't be able to sort numerically with the `K` in there, and second ... it's dismissing the other numbers. If that's okay, then perhaps I misunderstood your intent.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
New_data_frame <- My_data_frame[, order(c(names(My_data_frame)))]
```

I think it should work because it will order the columns alphabetically

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think this is because the programm thinks that V1.1. and V1.14.. is in "alphabetical" order as both include "V1.1". Maybe one could tell the programm to sort by the number behind K? Because here the order is always from 1 - 21.